# Other users can't access my Facebook App - it's OK for me, the owner of the app

Tags: facebook, request

I m working on an application 100002607637159, and i cannot access this app from other ids, on going to the app url from other ids, i'm receiving message

`The page you requested was not found.`

Please help, I don't understand why it would be OK for me, but not for other users

Answer (score 2):

Have you forgotten to take your app out of sandbox mode?

Comment: @MohsinRasheed When you are able, please accept Igy's answer so others can see that your question has a solution.  Cheers~

Comment: +1 I just did something similar. Was racking my brains... how come I can register on my app, but my wife can't?! Answer: because she isn't a nerd and so has a real job and thus is not a Facebook developer :-D